# Double substitution for an array in bash

Tags: bash

I have few arrays in my script

```
a=(1 2 3)
b=(3 4 5)
```

User inputs which list he wants to print out.

```
./array.sh a
```

How do I print the elements of array?

I have tried doing the following and couldn't print

```
array=$1
echo ${!array[@]}
```

Comment: What is your bash version?

Comment: GNU bash, version 4.3.11(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `declare -n` for named reference of your variables like this:

```
a=(1 2 3)
b=(3 4 5)

declare -n arr="${1?need an array name}"

printf "%s\n" "${arr[@]}"
```

Then execute it as:

```
./array.sh a
1
2
3

./array.sh b
3
4
5
```

Comment: `declare -n array=$1` works fine. thanks

Answer (score 1):

Make the `[@]` part of your indirection:

```
a=(1 2 3)

myfunction() {
  array="$1[@]"
  echo "${!array}"
}

myfunction a
```

Comment: I have so many arrays in my script. So `set -- a` may not scale well in my case :) But I get the logic behind your commands. Thanks.

Comment: @pdna This is just how you set `$1` from within the script to make it self-contained and runnable. It's easier to copy-paste and reproduce than having to create a script and run it with certain parameters. I changed it to set it via a function instead